# Adding more details after an error message in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have a function similar to the one below where a matrix is created within a loop.

```
foo <- function(x, y, z) {
  out <- list(a1 = NULL, a2 = NULL, a3 = NULL)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    t <- 100 * i
    a <- matrix(x, y + t, z)
    out[[i]] <- t(a)
  }
  return(out)
}
```

The following runs fine.
    p <- foo(NA, 100, 50)

But the following gives the `cannot allocate vector of length` error

```
q <- foo(NA, 3500000, 50)
```

I want to add some additional `message` like `adjust arguments 'y' and 'z'` after the `cannot allocate vector of length` or `too many elements specified` errors whenever they occur in my function.

I am trying `try` and `tryCatch`, but can't seem to get the desired result when the error is occurring within a loop. How to do this?

Comment: There is the `try` and `tryCatch` code you've tried? And you can you specify what the precise "desired result" is for this test?

Comment: If function stops with `Error: cannot allocate vector of size`, or `too many elements specified` give an additional message `adjust arguments 'y' and 'z'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enrich the error message with a simple decorator pattern:

```
safify <- function(f){
    function(...){
        tryCatch({
            f(...)
        },
        error=function(e){
            msg=conditionMessage(e)
            if(grepl("cannot allocate", msg)){
                msg=paste(msg, " Adjust arguments 'y' and 'z'", sep='.')
                return(msg)
            }
            msg
        })
    }
}

safefoo = safify(foo)

#res=safefoo(NA, 3500000, 50)
#> res
#[1] "cannot allocate vector of size 667.6 Mb. Adjust arguments 'y' and 'z'"
```

This way you catch every type of error which might occur and you enrich the one you want.